# Headphones don't work on Asus K55V

Tags: sound, asus, headphones, speakers

I have an Asus K55V. After loading Ubuntu 12.04, I didn't get any sound on my headphones. My speakers work fine... Can you help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on K55V laptop. Thanks to some posts at Ubuntu Forums I found a workaround for this:

- Headphones will work for you after shutdown and then startup of
  laptop (reboot does not help).
- Then headphones will bread for you after any reboot or suspend to
  disk. Suspend to RAM does not break anything.

For now I was not able to find full solution for this problem but shutdown looks like good workaround. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

set /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf file adding at the end of the file the following

options snd-hda-intel position-fix=1

and login again or reboot. It works for me